# Find $\dim\{ W \in \mathscr{L}(V) \ |\ WT =TW \}$ when $T = T^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Problem**
>
> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T \in
>  \mathscr{L}(V) $ such that $T = T^{-1}$.
>
> Suppose $S = \{ W \in \mathscr{L}(V) \ |\ WT =TW \}$.
>
> What is the dimension of  $S$ (in terms of the dimension of $V$ and
>   the trace of $T$)?

I know that $T$ is diagonalizable since $T^2-I = 0$ and the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $(\lambda+1)(\lambda-1)$, which has no repeated factors. Does this help 
 solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observation is indeed helpful.  Up to a change of basis (i.e. up to matrix similarity), we may state that $T$ is the matrix
$$
T = \pmatrix{I_{k_1}&0\\0 & -I_{k_2}}
$$
Where $I_k$ denotes the $k \times k$ identity matrix, $k_1 = \dim \ker (T - I)$, and $k_2 = \dim \ker (T + I)$.  Of course, $k_1 + k_2 = \dim V$.

Now, partition the matrix $W$ into blocks of the same size.  We note that $W$ commutes with $T$ if and only if it has the form 
$$
W = \pmatrix{W_{11} & 0\\0 & W_{22}}
$$
Conclude that $\dim(S) = k_1^2 + k_2^2$.

Comment: And observe that $k_1^2+k_2^2=\frac12\left((k_1+k_2)^2+(k_1-k_2)^2\right)$.

Comment: Your observation is indeed helpful.  Up to a change of basis (i.e. up to matrix similarity), we may state that $T$ is the matrix
$$
T = \pmatrix{I_{k_1}&0\\0 & -I_{k_2}}
$$
Where $I_k$ denotes the $k \times k$ identity matrix, $k_1 = \dim \ker (T - I)$, and $k_2 = \dim \ker (T + I)$.  Of course, $k_1 + k_2 = \dim V$.
I understood till here. Can you tell me why to partition the matrix $W$ into blocks of the same size?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri that's an interesting approach.  I would have noted that $k_1 = \frac 12 (\operatorname{Tr}(T) + \dim(V))$, and $k_2 = \dim(V) - k_1$.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan the idea is to use block-matrix multiplication.  For instance: if we partition $W$ into blocks of the same size, we can write
$$
\pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & -I}\pmatrix{W_{11}&W_{12}\\W_{21} & W_{22}} = 
\pmatrix{I\,W_{11}&I\,W_{12}\\-I\,W_{21} & -I\,W_{22}} = 
\pmatrix{W_{11}&W_{12}\\-W_{21} & -W_{22}}
$$